# Behavior of Single.fromObservable()

Tags: rx-java, observable, rx-java2

The docs for `Single.fromObservable()` say "If the source `Observable` has more than one element, an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is signaled." But this could never happen if the subscription is disposed immediately after receipt (and re-emission) of the `Observable`'s first element. The `Single` would have to maintain the subscription until it received either `onNext()` [causing the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`], `onComplete()` [presumably causing it to unsubscribe from the `Observable`], or `onError` [presumably passed downstream].

How and when does this operator deal with unsubscribing from the source `Observable`? Is the documentation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the documentation is correct. If you are in doubt, check the [source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/operators/observable/ObservableSingleSingle.java#L75):

```java
public void onNext(T t) {
    if (done) {
        return;
    }
    if (value != null) {
        done = true;
        s.dispose();
        actual.onError(new IllegalArgumentException("Sequence contains more than one element!"));
        return;
    }
    value = t;
}
```

> But this could never happen if the subscription is disposed immediately after receipt (and re-emission) of the Observable's first element.

The operator does not dispose after the first emission but only after the second item, which yields the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

After that, the `onComplete` [is responsible](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/operators/observable/ObservableSingleSingle.java#L99) for emitting the single item (or a default one):

```java
@Override
public void onComplete() {
    if (done) {
        return;
    }
    done = true;
    T v = value;
    value = null;
    if (v == null) {
        v = defaultValue;
    }

    if (v != null) {
        actual.onSuccess(v);
    } else {
        actual.onError(new NoSuchElementException());
    }
}
```